# vnc server on osx

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, remote-desktop, screen-sharing

I am running OSX lion on a 11" MBP and I want to connect to it remotely from a PC. Any suggestions for a good VNC server program? I have tried the OSX screen sharing function and also vine. They both work, but the screen size is limited to 11" -- I would like to be able to set the size of the shared screen (like the -geometry option for vncserver on linux). I'd also like to be able to maintain connection to it after the lid is closed. Is it possible to do that on OSX? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why necessarily VNC ? A very good software is team viewer, you only need to install it on your both PC and Mac. You can resize your screen as you want. 
Otherwise, vnc server (on your pc to command) + vnc viewer (on you mac to command) is fine. For the viewer, there is an add-on for google chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use clamshell mode with a larger, external display in order to get larger than your built-in 11" display over vnc. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2335260?tstart=0
There doesn't appear to be any other option.